# How to generate an irreducible polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

What is a method to generate an irreducible polynomial, no matter if a general method or only special case method?
I want a general formula like generating prime number to generate irreducible polynomial

I want to use this as a variety to generate an ideal such that $\mathrm{variety} = u_1 \cdot f_1 + u_2 \cdot f_2$, find $f_1$ and $f_2$, but I still do not know where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are coming from.
Any idea about this too?

Comment: your question is not very understandable. Can you perhaps edit it to explain what you mean? perhaps give some examples?

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: I can't make sense of your explanation.

Comment: I'm just curious: what would be a general formula to generate prime numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate polynomials irreducible over the rationals, you can use [Eisenstein's Criterion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)

This is far from providing a method for producing **all** polynomials irreducible over the rationals. By making a linear change of variable, one can make irreducible polynomials that don't **look** as if they were produced by using Eisensteins's Criterion.

Comment: it seems only this for variety

Comment: after read, i thought this (p+1)*a_n + (anynumber)*a_n-1... + (p^2+1)

Comment: The simplest Eisenstein-type general example is $x_n+pa_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +pa_1x+p$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a special case method over the real numbers:

- Pick $x^2 + 1$

A general method for rational numbers is

- Pick a polynomial by any method you want
- Factor the polynomial
- If it is reducible, go back to step 1

Comment: That is hardly efficient, particularly for large degree.

Comment: Similar:https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/~chandan/courses/CNT/notes/lec9.pdf